# Sentinel-1 radar data all zeros with Python SentinelHub API

Tags: python, sentinel-1, sentinel-hub, sentinel

I am requesting Sentinel-1 SAR data but rather than throwing an error the code is just returning zeros.

My request:

```
bbox = BBox([-145.8, 60.96, -146.5, 61.38], crs=CRS.WGS84)
bbox_size = bbox_to_dimensions(bbox, resolution=100)
time_interval = ('2018-07-01', '2018-07-16')

evalscript_all_bands = """
    //VERSION=3
    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["HV"],
            }],
            output: {
                bands: 1,
            }
        };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.HV];
    }
"""

request_all_bands = SentinelHubRequest(
    evalscript=evalscript_all_bands,
    input_data=[
        SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
            data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL1_EW,
            time_interval=time_interval,
    )],
    responses=[
        SentinelHubRequest.output_response('default', MimeType.TIFF)
    ],
    bbox=bbox,
    size=bbox_size,
    config=config
)

data = request_all_bands.get_data()

print(len(data))

print(data[0][:,:].shape)

plt.imshow(data[-1][::],aspect='auto')
```

The output of this is an array of zeros - no error message. Can anybody suggest a time period or region where I can find some data?

Comment: I've since found a part of the website that gives you snippets of code to use (under 'layers'). But using that gives me the same result:

//VERSION=3

function evaluatePixel(sample) {
    return [sample.HH, sample.HV, sample.dataMask];
}

function setup() {
  return {
    input: [{
      bands: [
        "HH",
        "HV",
        "dataMask"
      ]
    }],
    output: {
      bands: 3,
      sampleType:"FLOAT32"
    }
  }
}

Comment: This is because you are searching for EW collection (SENTINEL1_EW), which is not available there. IW is much more common.

Answer (score 1):

The EW mode is quite rare, only available for specific regions, see the Sentinel-1 [Observation scenario](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/data/sentinel-1-grd/#observation-scenarios).

If you want these specific type of data, you can e.g. find them here, for the same time period:

```
bbox = BBox([-145.8, 60.96, -146.5, 61.38], crs=CRS.WGS84)
```

If you are not certain, where there are some data, I suggest to use [EO Browser](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser), select Sentinel-1, then "Advanced search" and filter for the type you are interested in.
[image]

There is no error message as there is simply no data here.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as the correct answer once enough time has expired.